# How to pass a variable from an html form to a php script?

Tags: php, html

I have watched some tutorials on how to pass a variable from a form to a php file, and cannot get anything to happen when I click the submit button. I am making a page that searches the Clash of Clans API to display the clan searched.

I just need to have the form submit the clan tag to the php script.

Here is my code. The file is a php file and the form action is blank because the php is in the file.

```
                  <?php
                  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

                  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $clantag = $_POST['var'];
                  }

                  $token = Token Goes Here;

                  $url = "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/" . urlencode($clantag);

                  $ch = curl_init($url);

                  $headr = array();
                  $headr[] = "Accept: application/json";
                  $headr[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token;

                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                  $res = curl_exec($ch);
                  $data = json_decode($res, true);
                  curl_close($ch);

                  echo "<pre>";
                  var_dump($data);
                  echo "</pre>";
                  ?>

                  <form action="" method="post">
                      <input id="clan-tag" type="text" name="var" value="" />
                      <input id="clanSearchBtn" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
                  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the type of the button from "button" to "submit"

```
              <form action="" method="post">
                  <input id="clan-tag" type="text" name="var" value="" />
                  <input id="clanSearchBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
              </form>
```

Comment: That's it, bummer when it comes down to something so small